Automatically type command in powershell in visual studio code
I have a conda project with visual studio code. I wish that, every time in the project folder when I open my powershell, the command conda activate v_env is executed automatically. From the answer here, VSCode: How to run a command after each terminal open?, I create a json document :
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
      "My PowerShell": {
        "path": "pwsh.exe",
        "args": ["-noexit", "-file", "conda activate v_env"]
      }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "My PowerShell"
}

I tried:

Name the file settings.json and put it in .vscode.
Name the file tasks.json and put it in .vscode.

But neither of the two works. When I open powershell, it is like nothing was typed. I believe that this is because I did not put the json at a correct location or I did not use the script correctly. How do I proceed?

As the parameter -file suggests, it expects a script file for initialization - not a command.
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "My PowerShell": {
        "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
        "args": ["-noexit", "-file", "${env:APPDATA}\\MyPowerShell-init-script.ps1"] # C:\Users\fgrimps\AppData\Roaming or any path you like
        },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "My PowerShell"            
}

But if you only run a single command you can also use -command instead of -file as mentioned by Daniel.
See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles

So I should create a second file MyPowerShell-init-script.ps1, which is essentially text file with conda activate v_env, in the location I specify?

@温泽海, yes, you can do that or you can change -File to -Command which will treat the next argument as a command instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh?view=powershell-7.4#-command---c

This does not work. How should I name this json file in visual studio code? I added another file MyPowerShell-init-script.ps1 which contains just one line conda acticate v_env and pasted the path. Nothing changes.

I tested this on my system and it works as intended. As mentioned in the linked documentation you add this to your settings.json. Check this example settings.json https://pastebin.com/9jREKPrD in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json
